Automatic provisioning of Cisco Phone 8811 with 3pcc on Freepbx local server
I have a cp-8811 with 3pcc
I would like to know if it is possible to setup automatic provisioning with the test freepbx server that i have. The phone works fine with pjsip setted up manualy on the server. But i deleted the configuration to try this .
I have a DHCP server configured with options 66 and 150, as well as a tftp server setted up on the same machine as freepbx.
Is this possible without paid plugins?
And if so how? meaning i cant find a way to push the correct configuration to the phone.
(I don't understand what kind of template in xml is need, If it is needed at all, or i am missing something)
if so what would the steps be to set it up.
FreePBX 15.0.37.9
Asterisk 16.30.0
Software on phone:sip88xx.12-0-6Mpp0001-65.loads
Thanks in advance

I think it is not possible without paid plugins.
You need add-on EndPoint Manager. However, check compatibility first: https://sangomakb.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PG/pages/32080709/EPM-Supported+Devices
Some information about the 8800 series and FreePBX can be found here: https://community.freepbx.org/t/freepbx-support-for-newer-cisco-phones/63277
Alternatively, you can program your own solution / your own plugin into FreePBX.
